# How to say "It was great to see you" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the most natural translation of the English phrase "It was great to see you" (as in what you would say after seeing a friend you hadn't seen for a long time)?

Comment: Colombian way: ¡Rico verte!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say

> Me dio gusto verte.

Comment: This is very country dependent. Never heard it in Spain.

Answer (score 10):

More formal:

> Encantado/a de verte/haberte visto (de nuevo)

Less formal:

> Me alegro de verte
>
> Me ha alegrado verte

Informal:

> Que genial verte
>
> Cuánto tiempo
>
> Que guay (I think just Spain and kind of childish/posh)
>   verte/encontrarte

Answer (score 3):

In Mexico we say:

> ¡Qué milagro!

Comment: I dont think that you should put question mark as its not an interrogative sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told by a Spaniard:

> ¡Buen conocerte!

**Note:** As per Joel's comments below, this isn't universally recognised

Comment: Never ever heard that in Spain, especially because in Spain "conocerte" means to meet you for the first time, and the question is about meeting/seeing again. If someone told me "buen conocerte", I would know he/she is not from Spain.

Comment: Ah. The "de nuevo" was my addition, but the guy was from Málaga and that was how he said goodbye. Perhaps it's a regional phrase?

Comment: Either he was not Spaniard native or it's just I've never heard of it.

Comment: Perhaps you misheard it and he was actually saying *Qué bien conocerte*. // Note that a usage by *one person* might not mean anything.  It could be a quirky person trying to sound original.